Masterlist of book series?
As my mathematics department's library liaison, I would find it useful to have a master list of series of advanced mathematics books (whether monographs, texts, or proceedings).  Once I know the name of a series, I can find most all the actual titles via MathSciNet, but I don't know any way to extract a list of ongoing series from that database (am I missing something)?  It would also be of some value to know, for example, if the series is now defunct, or if the volumes are numbered whether there are gaps that correspond to no actual book.  I don't even know where to find a list of all the relevant publishers.

This is a cheap and dirty attempt.  There may be omissions and errors.
Springer:
AIMS Library Series
Advances in Applied Mathematics
Applied Mathematical Sciences (AMS)
Birkhäuser Mathematics
CIM Series in Mathematical Sciences
CRM Monograph Series
Compact Textbooks in Mathematics
Developments in Mathematics
Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete (Results in Mathematics and Related Areas)
Fields Institute Monographs
Frontiers in Mathematics (FIM)
Graduate Texts in Mathematics (GTM)
Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften (Fundamental Principles of Mathematical Sciences)
History of Mathematics Subseries (Springer/Birkhäuser)
INDAM Series
Interdisciplinary Applied Mathematics (IAM)
Lecture Notes in Mathematics (LNM)
Mathematical Biology
Mathematics and Its Applications
Modern Birkhäuser Classics
Moscow Lectures
Probability Theory and Stochastic Modelling
Problem Books in Mathematics
Progress in Mathematics
Quantitative Finance
SMF/AMS Texts and Monographs
Springer Briefs in Mathematics
Springer Monographs in Mathematics
Springer Optimization and Its Applications
Springer Proceedings in Mathematics & Statistics (PROMS)
Springer Series in Computational Mathematics
Springer Undergraduate Mathematics Series (SUMS)
SpringerBriefs in Mathematics
Student Mathematical Library
Texts and Readings in Mathematics (jointly with Hindustan Book Agency)
Texts in Applied Mathematics (TAM)
The Mathematical Intelligencer Book Series
Theoretical and Mathematical Physics
Tracts in Mathematics
Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics (UTM)
Undergraduate Topics in Mathematics (UTiM)
Universitext

AMS Monograph and Book Series:
Graduate Studies in Mathematics (GSM)
Mathematical Surveys and Monographs (MSM)
Memoirs of the American Mathematical Society
Colloquium Publications
Translations of Mathematical Monographs
University Lecture Series
AMS Chelsea Publishing
Proceedings of Symposia in Pure Mathematics
Proceedings of Symposia in Applied Mathematics
AMS/IP Studies in Advanced Mathematics (co-published with International Press)
Contemporary Mathematics
History of Mathematics
Student Mathematical Library
Pure and Applied Undergraduate Texts
Mathematical World
Fields Institute Monographs (co-published with Fields Institute)
IAS/Park City Mathematics Series
CBMS Regional Conference Series in Mathematics
Clay Mathematics Monographs (co-published with Clay Mathematics Institute)
Clay Mathematics Proceedings (co-published with Clay Mathematics Institute)
CRM Monograph Series (co-published with Centre de Recherches Mathématiques)
CRM Proceedings & Lecture Notes (co-published with Centre de Recherches Mathématiques)
DIMACS Series in Discrete Mathematics and Theoretical Computer Science
AMS Non-Series Monographs

EMS Monograph and Book Series:
EMS Monographs in Mathematics
EMS Tracts in Mathematics
EMS Series of Congress Reports
EMS Series in Industrial and Applied Mathematics
EMS Series of Lectures in Mathematics
EMS Textbooks in Mathematics
Heritage of European Mathematics
IRMA Lectures in Mathematics and Theoretical Physics
Zürich Lectures in Advanced Mathematics
Oberwolfach Seminars
Portals of Mathematics
RSME Springer Series (co-published with RSME and Springe

Princeton University Press:
Annals of Mathematics Studies
Lectures in Modern Analysis and Applications
Mathematical Notes
Monographs in Population Biology
Primers in Complex Systems
Princeton Classics in Mathematics
Princeton Companion Series
Princeton Frontiers in Mathematics
Princeton Landmarks in Mathematics and Physics
Princeton Lectures in Analysis
Princeton Legacy Library
Princeton Mathematical Series
Princeton Puzzlers
Princeton Science Library
Princeton Series in Algorithmic and Computational Mathematics
Princeton Series in Applied Mathematics
Princeton Series in Complexity
Princeton Series in Mathematical Physics
Princeton Series in Quantitative Finance
Princeton Series in Theoretical and Computational Biology
Problems in Mathematical Analysis
Studies in Nonlinear Dynamics and Complexity

Cambridge University Press:
Cambridge Aerospace Series (Mathematics Volumes)
Cambridge Elements in the Philosophy of Mathematics
Cambridge International Mathematics for the IB Diploma
Cambridge Library Collection - Mathematics
Cambridge Mathematical Library
Cambridge Mathematical Textbooks
Cambridge Modular Mathematics
Cambridge Monographs on Applied and Computational Mathematics
Cambridge Monographs on Mathematical Physics
Cambridge Perspectives in Mathematical Physics
Cambridge Series in Chemical Engineering (Mathematical Volumes)
Cambridge Series in Statistical and Probabilistic Mathematics
Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics
Cambridge Studies in Mathematical Biology
Cambridge Studies in the History of Mathematics
Cambridge Texts in Applied Mathematics
Cambridge Texts in Theoretical Computer Science
Cambridge Tracts in Mathematics
Encyclopedia of Mathematics and Its Applications
London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series
Mathematics in Science and Engineering
New Mathematical Monographs
Perspectives in Logic
The Millennium Mathematics Project

Oxford University Press:
Clarendon Series in Mathematics
International Series of Monographs on Physics (Mathematical Volumes)
Landmark Writings in Western Mathematics
London Mathematical Society Monographs
Numerical Mathematics and Scientific Computation
Oxford Applied Mathematics and Computing Science Series
Oxford Classics in Mathematics
Oxford Financial Mathematics
Oxford Graduate Texts in Applied Mathematics
Oxford Graduate Texts in Mathematics
Oxford Lecture Series in Mathematics and Its Applications
Oxford Logic Guides
Oxford Master Series in Mathematics and Physics
Oxford Mathematical Handbooks
Oxford Mathematical Monographs
Oxford Mathematical and Computational Biology
Oxford Monographs on Geology and Geophysics (Mathematical Volumes)
Oxford Series in Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications
Oxford Series in Probability and Statistics
Oxford Series on Materials Modelling
Oxford Studies in Nonlinear Science
Oxford Studies in the Philosophy of Mathematics and Logic
Oxford Texts in Applied and Engineering Mathematics
Oxford Texts in Logic
Princeton Mathematical Series (OUP collaboration)
The Carus Mathematical Monographs (OUP editions)
The Institute of Mathematics and its Applications (IMA) Series

de Gruyter Mathematics Series:
De Gruyter Studies in Mathematics
De Gruyter Expositions in Mathematics
De Gruyter Series in Nonlinear Analysis and Applications
Frontiers in Mathematics
Classical and Modern Geometry
The Classical Heritage in Mathematics
Atlantis Studies in Mathematics (co-published with Atlantis Press)
Springer de Gruyter Series (co-published with Springer)
Radon Series on Computational and Applied Mathematics
Advances in Mathematics
Advanced Textbooks in Mathematics

Elsevier Mathematics Series:
North-Holland Mathematical Library
Studies in Mathematics and Its Applications
Mathematics in Science and Engineering
North-Holland Series in Applied Mathematics and Mechanics
Handbook of Mathematical Logic
Handbook of Numerical Analysis
Handbook of Statistics (mathematics-statistics crossover)
Developments in Mathematics
Annals of Discrete Mathematics
Computer Science and Applied Mathematics (historically significant, now largely inactive)

World Scientific Publishing:
World Scientific Series in 20th Century Mathematics
Contemporary Mathematics and Its Applications
Mathematical Olympiad Series
Series on Knots and Everything
Advances in Mathematics Education
Series on Complexity Science
Lecture Notes Series, Institute for Mathematical Sciences, National University of Singapore
Mathematical Biology and Medicine Series
World Scientific Monographs in Mathematics
Asian Mathematics Series
World Scientific Series in Applicable Analysis
Series in Real Analysis
Developments in Mathematics
Geometry and Topology

Birkhäuser:
Progress in Mathematics
Modern Birkhäuser Classics
Advanced Courses in Mathematics - CRM Barcelona
Trends in Mathematics
Frontiers in Mathematics
Applied and Numerical Harmonic Analysis
Lecture Notes in Mathematics
Operator Theory: Advances and Applications
Basler Lehrbücher (Birkhäuser Advanced Texts)
Monographs in Mathematics
Geosciences, Environmental Science, and Engineering (related to mathematics applications)
Modeling and Simulation in Science, Engineering, and Technology
Mathématiques et Applications   

Kluwer:
Encyclopaedia of Mathematics (and its supplementary volumes).
Mathematics and Its Applications.
Mathematical Modelling: Theory and Applications.
NATO Science Series C: Mathematical and Physical Sciences.

Wiley:
Pure and Applied Mathematics: A Wiley Series of Texts, Monographs, and Tracts
Wiley Series in Discrete Mathematics and Optimization
Wiley Series in Probability and Statistics
Wiley Series in Computational Mathematics
Wiley Series in Operations Research and Management Science
Wiley Series in Mathematical and Computational Biology
Wiley-Interscience Series in Discrete Mathematics and Optimization

AK Peters/CRC Press (now part of Taylor & Francis):
AK Peters/CRC Recreational Mathematics Series
Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications
Textbooks in Mathematics
Chapman & Hall/CRC Mathematics Series
Advances in Applied Mathematics

Taylor & Francis, which includes CRC Press and Routledge:
AK Peters/CRC Recreational Mathematics Series
Chapman & Hall/CRC Texts in Statistical Science
Chapman & Hall/CRC Monographs and Surveys in Pure and Applied Mathematics
Chapman & Hall/CRC Financial Mathematics Series
Chapman & Hall/CRC Research Notes in Mathematics
Textbooks in Mathematics
Advances in Applied Mathematics 

International Press of Boston:
Advanced Lectures in Mathematics
AMS/IP Studies in Advanced Mathematics (jointly with the AMS)
Current Developments in Mathematics
Gökova Geometry-Topology Conferences
Harvard CMSA Series in Mathematics
Morningside Lectures in Mathematics
Ramanujan Lecture Notes Series
Surveys in Differential Geometry
Surveys of Modern Mathematics   

Société Mathématique de France (SMF):
Astérisque
Cours Spécialisés
Documents Mathématiques
Panoramas & Synthèses
Série Chaire Jean Morlet
Séminaires et Congrès
SMF/AMS Texts and Monographs    

Mathematical Association of America (MAA):
MAA Textbooks
MAA Notes
Dolciani Mathematical Expositions
Spectrum Series
Carus Mathematical Monographs
Anneli Lax New Mathematical Library
Classroom Resource Materials
MAA Problem Book Series 

